# Angular 12 - Error : No overload matches this call. Overload 1 of 5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient, angular12

The following is my code:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  isAuth$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  token!: string ; 
  userId!: string;

  constructor(private router: Router,
    private http: HttpClient) { }


  createNewUser(email: string, password: string) {
    return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.post(
        'http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signup',
        { email: email, password: password })
        .subscribe(
          () => {
            this.login(email, password).then(
              () => {
                resolve();
              }
            ).catch(
              (error) => {
                reject(error);
              }
            );
          },
          (error) => {
            reject(error);
          }
        );
    });
  }

  login(email: string, password: string) {
    return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.post(
        'http://localhost:3000/api/auth/login',
        { email: email, password: password })
        .subscribe(
          (authData: { token: string, userId: string }) => {  //====> Error 
            this.token = authData.token;
            this.userId = authData.userId;
            this.isAuth$.next(true);
            resolve();
          },
          (error) => {
            reject(error);
          }
        );
    });
  }

  logout() {
    this.isAuth$.next(false);
    this.userId = null!;
    this.token = null!;
  }
}
```

Error description:

> No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 5, '(next: null, error:
> (error: any) => void, complete?: () => void): Subscription', gave the
> following error.
> Argument of type '(authData: {    token: string;    userId: string;}) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'null'.
> Overload 2 of 5, '(next?: (value: Object) => void, error?: (error:
> any) => void, complete?: () => void): Subscription', gave the
> following error.
> Argument of type '(authData: {    token: string;    userId: string;}) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value:
> Object) => void'.
> Types of parameters 'authData' and 'value' are incompatible.
> The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
> Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type '{ token: string; userId: string; }': token, userId

[The following is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXRjE.png)

[Error description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYyL1.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to specify the response data type that is expected to receive for `this.http.post`.

**Solution 1**: Specify as `{ token: string, userId: string }` type

```js
login(email: string, password: string) {
    return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.post<{ token: string, userId: string }>(
        'http://localhost:3000/api/auth/login',
        { email: email, password: password })
        .subscribe(
          (authData: { token: string, userId: string }) => { 
            this.token = authData.token;
            this.userId = authData.userId;
            this.isAuth$.next(true);
            resolve();
          },
          (error) => {
            reject(error);
          }
        );
    });
  }
```

**Solution 2**: Specify as `any` type

```js
login(email: string, password: string) {
    return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.post<any>(
        'http://localhost:3000/api/auth/login',
        { email: email, password: password })
        .subscribe(
          (authData: { token: string, userId: string }) => { 
            this.token = authData.token;
            this.userId = authData.userId;
            this.isAuth$.next(true);
            resolve();
          },
          (error) => {
            reject(error);
          }
        );
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the generic type of `this.http.post` function to be `{ token: string, userId: string }` like the following:

```js
this.http.post<{ token: string, userId: string }>(......);
```

However, I think it's better in your case to use `Observable` directly without   `promise`, and without subscription within your function.

You can achieve that like the following:

```js
  login(email: string, password: string): Observable<void> {
    return this.http
      .post<{ token: string; userId: string }>(
        "http://localhost:3000/api/auth/login",
        {
          email: email,
          password: password,
        }
      )
      .pipe(
        map((authData) => {
          this.token = authData.token;
          this.userId = authData.userId;
          this.isAuth$.next(true);
        })
      );
  }
```